# Cardinality of set of fractional sums

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

What is the cardinality of the set $S_2$:

$$ \frac{1}{a_1^n} + \frac{1}{a_2^n}, 1 \leq a_1,a_2 \leq k \in N$$

for different values of $n$?

I suspect there is an $n_0$ for which $|S_2| = \binom{k+1}{2}, \forall n \geq n_0$.

Is there such an $n_0$ for all sets $S_m$:

$$ \frac{1}{a_1^n} + \frac{1}{a_2^n} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a_m^n}, 1 \leq a_i \leq k$$

i.e. $n_0: |S_m| = \binom{k+m-1}{m}, \forall n \geq n_0$?

#### Example:

For the set $S_2$, with $k=3, n=2$:

$$ S = \{\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{1}+ \frac{1}{2^2}, \ldots, \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} \} = \{ 2, \frac{5}{4}, \frac{10}{9}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{13}{36}, \frac{2}{9} \}$$

so $$ |S_2(k=3,n=2)| = 6 $$

Comment: I think your question should be tagged [combinatorics] and [elementary-number-theory], not [set-theory] and [cardinals].

Comment: A better way to express this would be: is it true that for every $k, m \in \Bbb{N}$, s.t. $m \geq 2$ and $k \geq 1$, there is an $n_0 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that the numbers
$$
\frac{1}{a_1^n} + \dotsb + \frac{1}{a_m^n}
$$
with $a_1,\dotsc,a_m \in \{1,\dotsc,k\}$ are all different for every $n \geq n_0$?

Comment: By the way, the symbol $S_n$ is less than ideal, because your set depends on $k$ and $n$, too. Thus a symbol like $S_2(k,n)$ or $S_{2,k}(n)$ would be more appropriate. This is made even more important by the fact that you're asking about a property of this set in function of $n$.

Comment: I'm sorry: I can't edit it anymore, but in my previous comment I should have said "with $1 \leq a_1 \leq \dotsc \leq a_n \leq k$".

Comment: @A.P. thanks for your comments. I'm also interested in the cardinality of the set, not just a proof of existence of $n_0$. I used $S_x$ instead of $S_{m,k,n}$ (or whatever) to remove some clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proposition.** For each $m, k\ge 2$, $|S_m(k,n)|={k+m-1\choose m}$ for each $n\ge \log_{\frac k{k-1}} m-1$.

*Proof*. We shall follow A.P.’s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615044/cardinality-of-set-of-fractional-sums#comment3293391_1615044). Let $\mathcal S$ be a family of non-decreasing sequences $(a_1,\dots, a_m)$ of natural numbers between $1$ and $k$. For each $S=(a_1,\dots, a_m)\in \mathcal S$ put  $\Sigma S=a_1^{-n}+\dots a_m^{-n}$. Since $|\mathcal S|={k+m-1\choose m}$,  we have to show that numbers  $\Sigma S$ are distinct when $S\in\mathcal S$. Suppose to the contrary, that there exists distinct sequences $S=(a_1,\dots, a_m)$ and $T=(b_1,\dots, b_m)$ in $\mathcal S$ such that $\Sigma S=\Sigma T$. Let $i$ be the smallest number such that $a_i\ne b_i$. Without loss of generality we may suppose that $a_i<b_i$. Then

$$\Sigma S-\Sigma T\ge a^{-n}_i- b^{-n}_i+\sum_{j>i} a^{-n}_j - b^{-n}_j\ge$$ $$a^{-n}_i- b^{-n}_i+\sum_{j>i} k^{-n} - b^{-n}_i=$$ $$a^{-n}_i+(m-i)k^{-n}-(m-i+1)b^{-n}_i\ge$$ $$ a^{-n}_i+(m-i)k^{-n}-(m-i+1)(a_i+1)^{-n}\ge$$ $$ a^{-n}_i+(m-1)k^{-n}-m(a_i+1)^{-n}=f(a_i),$$

where $f(x)=x^{-n}+(m-1)k^{-n}-m(x+1)^{-n}$. Since $f(k-1)=(k-1)^{-n}-k^{-n}>0$, to obtain a contradiction it suffices to show that 
$f’(x)<0$ for $1\le x<k-1$. Since $f’(x)=(-n)x^{-n-1}+nm(x+1)^{-n-1}$, we have to check that

$x^{-n-1}-m(x+1)^{-n-1}>0$

$x^{-n-1}>m(x+1)^{-n-1}$

$\left( x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{n+1}>m$

which is true, because $\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{n+1}>\left(1+\frac{1}{k-1}\right)^{n+1}\ge m$. $\square$